# How to use the properties of a class in the same class like they have values in C#

Tags: c#, class, properties

I am trying to use a property of a class in the same class to compare with another value.
However, this property is still empty because I do not have an instance of that class. See the example below.

```
public Zoo(string name, int capacity)
{
    Name = name;
    Capacity = capacity;    
}
public Zoo()
{
    AnimalsWhichCouldNotBeModified = new List<Animal>();
}
public List<Animal> AnimalsWhichCouldNotBeModified { get; set; }
public string  Name { get; set; }
public int Capacity { get; set; }

public string  AddAnimal(Animal animal)
{
    // Here I have tried to use the property Capacity.
    // I have also tried to use "capacity" from the constructor.
    // I have also tried to create an instance of the Zoo class in the Zoo class, but it is still empty, so I am not sure if I can do that.  
    if (Capacity < AnimalsWhichCouldNotBeModified.Count)
    {
        return "The zoo is full.";
    }
```

How can I get the capacity (that is still not instanced and it is null) to be used in the example so I can check if the animals are more than the zoo capacity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you don't initialize `AnimalsWhichCouldNotBeModified` in the non-default constructor. You can either add the initialization into the non-default constructor:

```
public Zoo(string name, int capacity)
{
    Name = name;
    Capacity = capacity;    
    AnimalsWhichCouldNotBeModified = new List<Animal>();
}
```

or call the default one from the non-default:

```
public Zoo(string name, int capacity) : this()
{
    Name = name;
    Capacity = capacity;    
}

public Zoo()
{
    AnimalsWhichCouldNotBeModified = new List<Animal>();
}
```

or, third option, provide an initializer in the property's declaration:

```
public List<Animal> AnimalsWhichCouldNotBeModified { get; set; } = new List<Animal>();
```

I'd personally prefer this third option unless I needed a more complex initialization code in the constructor.

Note that when `Capacity` is not initialized, it will be 0 by default. This is because the underlying (compiler-generated) backing field is initialized to 0. The same holds for `AnimalsWhichCouldNotBeModified` and `Name` which are `null` by default.

Answer (score 0):

In your second constructor (`public Zoo()` that doesn't require any other parameters), you could just set your `Capacity = 0`.

Each time an instance is created, you're either going to use the first constructor, where you need to manually provide a `Capacity`, or the second constructor that is automatically going to set the `Capacity` to value **0**.

```
public Zoo(string name, int capacity)
{
    Name = name;
    Capacity = capacity;    
}
public Zoo()
{
    Capacity = 0;
    AnimalsWhichCouldNotBeModified = new List<Animal>();
}
public List<Animal> AnimalsWhichCouldNotBeModified { get; set; }
public string  Name { get; set; }
public int Capacity { get; set; }
public string  AddAnimal(Animal animal)
{
    // Here I have tried to use the property Capacity.
    // I have also tried to use "capacity" from the constructor.
    // I have also tried to create an instance of the Zoo class in the Zoo class, but it is still empty, so I am not sure if I can do that.  
    if (Capacity < AnimalsWhichCouldNotBeModified.Count)
    {
        return "The zoo is full.";
    }
}
```

Comment: No. `Capacity` will be 0 by default, this is how class (field) initialization works. The problem is he doesn't instantiate the list in the non-default constructor.